# Loading data from sqlite database into table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have created the database named 'Mydatabase.db' in sqlites 3 using terminal and created table named 'entries' with three column in it (name ,email ,food).
I used this code for connection with database in AppDelegate.m file

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.Peoples=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
        self.databaseName = @"MyDatabase.db";
        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentDir=[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
         self.databasePath=[documentDir stringByAppendingString:self.databaseName];

        [self CheckAndCreateDatabase];
        [self readDataFromDatabase];
        return YES;
    }
```

In above function i checked path of database file using NSLog output is empty string . 
 Then i used these functions for fetching the data -

```
(void)CheckAndCreateDatabase
    {
        bool success;
        NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
        success=[fileManger fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath];
        if (success)
            return;
        NSString *databasePathFromApp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName];
        [fileManger copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil];

    }

    -(void) readDataFromDatabase{
        [self.Peoples removeAllObjects ];
        sqlite3 *database;
        if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], & database) ==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *sqlStatement="select * from entries";
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
                while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                    char *n=sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
                    char *e=sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
                    char *f=sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3);
                    NSString *name=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:n];
                    NSString *email=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:e];
                    NSString *food=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:f];
                    NSLog(@"Name= %@",name);
                    Data *data =[[Data alloc] initWithData:name theEmail:email TheFood:food];
                    [self.Peoples addObject:data];
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```

Then in TableViewController.m i am displaying the retrieved data by using 'Data' object

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    SiteCell *cell=(SiteCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell=nil) {
        cell=[[SiteCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];
    }
    NSInteger row=indexPath.row;
    Data *d=[mainDelegate.Peoples objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.primaryLabal.text=d.name;
    cell.secondaryLabal.text=d.email;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;

}
```

How i can display the data in table view from database ?I am not getting data displayed on tableview reason can be database connection not established?.How i correct it and get the desired output ?You can download sample code from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnQkFySHkwZm9nR1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you need to refresh your latest data use `reload data` after this line `[self.Peoples addObject:data];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are collecting the data correctly but you forgot to update your table. Use [self.yourTableView reloadData];

afer this line

```
Data *data =[[Data alloc] initWithData:name theEmail:email TheFood:food];
                [self.Peoples addObject:data];
            }
          [self.yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: @frincit this is not empty, you are doing wrong to get documentPaths. You have to use NSLog(@"Path=%@" ,documentPaths). Check your edited question

Comment: Data *data =[[Data alloc] initWithData:name theEmail:email TheFood:food];
                    [self.Peoples addObject:data];  --> this line belong to  this function ' readDataFromDatabase' in AppDelegate.m i am not using any TableView in AppDelegate.m file

Comment: NSLog(@"Name= %@",name); in 'readDataFromDatabase' function is not displayed .infect  connection is  not established it doesn't compile these conditions-->           if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
                while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

Answer (score -1):

Use this repository for easy and small library

https://github.com/prashantbelani/DBOperation

You just need to change database name in DBOperation.m File.

E/g. databaseName=@"Emoji_app.rdb";

and In DBFunction file you can write methods to get data with **selectData** AND execute query with **executeSQL** 
Hope this will help you.